# CSS flexing with media screen size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a simple template for a website. I've included all code in the link below but just to give an idea I'm trying to change the layout of a 2 flex items when max-width: 600px;

Currently the layout looks like this:
[image]

This is a header, with a simple Flex set up, Left is Flex:1 (green), blue is Flex:2.

What I'm hoping to do is if max-width < 600px then put green part above the blue, and make them the same size. Here's my html and CSS, also adding a link to my codePen

HTML:

```
<body>
 <div class="top">

 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="mainContent">

  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.left{
flex:1;
height:auto;
background-color: green;
background-position: fixed;
}
.mainContent{
 flex:2;
 background-color:blue;
 height:100px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.mainContent{
  background-color: pink;
}
.wrapper{ <---- Here it's turning both the Green & blue into pink (doing this as test)
  flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

So I tried to already do it by setting

```
.wrapper{
flex:direction:column 
}
```

but that is turning the entire green and blue row into pink.

Any idea how I'd be able to format it so that green goes above blue and they are both same size? I'm trying to make this mobile friendly.

[LinktoCodepen](https://codepen.io/KooshKoosh/pen/aLeNwJ)

Comment: Everything works just fine, and if you add content to the green you can see it does: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MENyZb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a media query to set the `width` of both elements to 100%.

Then use the `flex-wrap` and the `order` properties to put your elements in the right place.

Your CSS would look roughly like this:

```
  body{
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
  }
  .top{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .wrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .left{
    flex:1;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    background-position: fixed;
  }
  .mainContent{
    flex:2;
    background-color:blue;
    height:100px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .mainContent{
      background-color: pink;
      min-width: 100%;
    }
    .left {
      min-width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

Here's an updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWMymE